# How to show my website favicon in Bing's search engine?

Tags: html, seo, favicon, bing

Here is a screenshot of Bing search engine:

[image: Favicon in Bing search engine]

Most of the websites have their favicon on the left side of their website title link. (Like the red circle) But my website in Bing search engine shows a gray earth icon, not my website's favicon. I'm sure that my website has `favicon.ico` (it is put in root directory), and I am also sure that I have add this code in `<head>...</head>` tag:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

But still look like this:

[image: No website icon]

So is there anyone knows that how to show my website's favicon in Bing search engine?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this if**:

```
Normal favicon:

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

PNG/GIF favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

in the <head> Tag.
```

If that doesnt work please try clearing your cache on Bing.
Also sometimes it wont load if the favicon is not uploaded to a webserver so think about that.